# Routing page state changes in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have an angular app which is simply a single page that displays an array of strings.

Now say I want to create a filter for my displayed strings, then append that filter to the page URL so the filtered results can be linked to. As example url might be, "/filter/myfilteredword"

In this example I would still want to use the same controller and I wouldn't want to use a template URL as there is only one page. I also need to be able to pass in the filtered string as a param.

I've tried to set this up using angulars $routeProvider and $routeParams, however I'm not having much luck and I'm not 100% sure this is the correct way to go about it.

Any advise would be really appreciated.

Comment: Provide your code, please.

Comment: Do you have to use the url? $filter will do what you want within the controller, without the filter showing in the url.